# Clueless: Infinite Loop in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, infinite

i am working on a c implementation of `Eratostenes` method of finding prime numbers and i am running into a very weird error.

```
int* criba(int n){

    int *array;
    int i,j,k,valor;
    array = malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for (i=0;i<=n-2;i++){
        array[i]=i+2;
    }

    for (j=0;j<n-2;j++){
        valor = array[j];
        for (k=1;valor*k+j<n-2;k++){

            printf("%d \n",array[valor*k+j]);

            }
        }
    }


    return array;
}
```

This works as intended, it creates an `n-2` sized array, with all the numbers from to 2 to n, then it checks every value and prints all of its multiples inside the array (Eratostenes's method seeks for all the multiples of a number starting from 2 and marks them in a `table`, then it goes to the next unmarked number, after that, all the unmarked number are prime numbers)

The problem is, when i try to zero the numbers to "mark" them, i get stuck in a loop for no reason at all:

```
int* criba(int n){

    int *array;
    int i,j,k,valor;
    array = malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for (i=0;i<=n-2;i++){
        array[i]=i+2;
    }

    for (j=0;j<n-2;j++){
        valor = array[j];
        for (k=1;valor*k+j<n-2;k++){
            if (array[valor*k+j] != 0){
                printf("%d \n",array[valor*k+j]);
                array[valor*k+j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }


    return array;
}
```

In fact, the only problem is `array[valor*k+j] = 0;`, if i remove that the program returns sucesfully, but with that line it gets stuck and i can't find why. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try again after removing `array[valor*k+j] = 0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously at some moment `valor = array[j];` will make `valor` equal to `0`, so the condition in loop `valor*k+j < n-2;` will always be true, hence the infinite loop.

Comment: I feel so silly now. What could be a decent solution, a duplicated array?

Comment: @user3502583 What about an early check for zero-ness?

Comment: Hahaha yes, i just did that, "if (valor !=0){" before the for loop fixes everything, thanks to everyone ^^

Answer (score 2):

You are looping forever because of the combination of `valor = array[j]` and `array[valor*k+j] = 0`; the inner loop zeroes out some later entries. Then on a future iteration of the outer loop, array[j] has already been zeroed, so valor  = 0, so the inner loop test is `(0 * k) + j < n-2` where j is held constant which is always false.

The simplest solution is do one pass to print the results, then a separate pass to loop through and zero things out.